# How to pre-process labels for multi-label classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm trying to create a basic model to perform multi-label image classification. However, I'm not able to figure out how to pre-process the labels for the training.

I'm using TFDS COCO dataset with 80 classes:

- Do I one-hot encode everything and then add them into a single vector? (I assume this wouldn't work well for images that have two of the same object)
- How to deal with the different shapes of labels (e.g. the case where an image has 2 classes, but the next one has 5)

This is my code so far:

```py
ds, ds_info = tfds.load('coco', split='train', with_info=True, shuffle_files=True)

n_classes = ds_info.features['objects']['label'].num_classes

def preprocess_image(example):
    image = example['image']
    bbox = example['objects']['bbox']
    label = example['objects']['label']

    # Resize the image and bounding box
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (299, 299))
    bbox = tf.reshape(bbox, (-1, 4))

  
    # One hot encode the labels
    label = tf.one_hot(label,
                        depth=n_classes)

    return image, label

ds = ds.map(preprocess_image)

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',
    include_top=False,
)

base_model.trainable = False

# Add the custom layers on top of the base model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

label_output = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=label_output)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=['categorical_crossentropy'],
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(ds.batch(32), epochs=1)
```

With the above model I get the error that the shapes of the labels are incompatible with the one in the model ValueError:

> `Shapes (None, None, 80) and (None, 80) are incompatible`